# Finding the product of first Million natural numbers in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function, out-of-memory

I have just started with Python programming language. I tried to write a function which takes input either a list or multiple integers to find their product. I am trying to find the product of first million natural numbers but its displaying an `MemoryError`.

```
def product(*arg):
    answer=1
    if type(arg) == tuple:
        arg=str(arg)
        arg=arg.lstrip('[(')
        arg=arg.rstrip('],)')
        arg=arg.split(',')
        for i in arg:
            answer*=int(i)
        return answer
    else:
        for i in arg:
            answer*=int(i)
        return answer

j=range(1,1000000,1)
j=list(j)
print(product(j))
```

Steps:

- I convert the range object into list object if i am to pass a list as
  argument
- Now, within the function, i try to split the tuple by converting it
  string.
- I convert the resultant string into a list and then loop over the
  elements to find the product

**Q1:**   How to avoid the memory error as i try to find the product of first Million natural numbers?

**Q2**    How to improve this code?

Comment: Why on earth are you converting your tuple to a string and back instead of just iterating over it directly like you do in the else statement?

Comment: As i pass the arg argument, it gets converted into a single elemented tuple.So, i am not able to iterate over it.

Comment: try `for i in arg[0]:` then

Comment: Thanks, ``arg[0]``  works in a way that i can directly loop over it. But the problem regarding finding the product of million numbers is still there.

Comment: For smaller numbers: `math.factorial(1000)` (`reduce(mul, range(1, 1000 + 1))`) but for `1000_000` the answer is too large: you could [use Stirling formula to estimate log of the answer: `n*log(n)-n`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation)

Answer (score 1):

To calculate the product of all numbers from 1 to 1 million use a simple loop:

```
r = 1
for l in range(1,1000000):
    r*=(i+1)
print(res)
```

But keep in mind that the result will be a pretty big number.
That means that your calculation might take long and the resulting number will need a lot memory.

**EDIT** Then i missread your question a little. This is a function that multiplies the elements in a list:

```
def multiply_list_elements(_list):
    result = 1
    for element in _list:
        result*=element
    return result

multiply_list_elements([1,2,3,4])

>>> 24
```

The memory error probably came from the huge number as @ZabirAlNazi calculated so nicely.

Comment: Thanks. But i was trying to create a function where i input any list of numbers and get the product. I mentioned first million numbers because while testing my function for it, it showed a memory error.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [Generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) in Python.

```
def generate_product():
    r = 1
    for i in range(1,1000000):
        r *= i + 1
        yield r

list(generate_product())[0]
```

It is more memory efficient and better in terms of performance.

Answer (score 0):

All of the solution is fine, but one point to make - your question is equivalent to find the factorial of 1 million.

The number of digits of n! = log10(1) + log10(2) + ... log10(n)

```
import math
num_dig = 1
for i in range(1,1000000):
  num_dig += math.log10(i)
print(num_dig)
```

So, the number of digits in your answer is `5565703` (approx.).

That's only the final `n`, if you also want the intermediate results it will require squared memory O(m^2).

```
import math
ans = 1
for i in range(2,1000001):
  ans *= i
print(ans)
```

N.B: You can approximate with logarithms and Stirling numbers with faster run-time.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple solution would be:

```
    def prod_of():
        p=1
        for i in range(1,1000000):
            p* = i
        print(p)
```